# Understanding why $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \cos z=x$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin z=y$

Tags: trigonometry, linear-transformations, 3d

Consider the map $T:(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, given by
$$\tag{1}
T(a, b)=(a \cos b, a \sin b, b)
$$
and the map $V$ defined from the image of $T$ into $(0,\infty)$ by
$$\tag{2}
V(x, y, z)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z\right)
$$
My teacher uses in a proof that for any $p\in (0,\infty)$ and any $q$ in the image of $T$ the following holds:
$$\tag{3}
V(T(p))=p,\qquad T(V(q))=q
$$
The left equality is simple to prove using $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$. Consider then an arbitrary $q=(x,y,z)$ in the image of $T$, and the right equality becomes:
$$\tag{4}
T(V(q))=T\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z\right)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \cos z, \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin z, z\right)
$$
Eq. $(3)$ then implies that we must have
$$\tag{5}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \cos z=x,\quad \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin z=y
$$
Can someone help me understand why the relations in eq. $(5)$ hold?

Comment: $q$ is not arbitrary: the value of $z$ sets the direction of $(x,y)$ in the $xy$ plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because (3) on the right tells you that $T(V(q)) = q$ by setting $q=(x,y,z)$ you get $T(V(x,y,z)) = (x,y,z)$ then using the equality in (4) you get $(x,y,z) = T(V(x,y,z)) = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos{z},\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin{z},z)$

Looking at the components this gives you $x = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos{z}$ and $y = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin{z}$

This of course relies on eq. (3)

If you want to prove (3) you just have to take q in the Image of T then $q = (x,y,z) = (a \cos{b} , a \sin{b}, b)$, this is because q is not any value in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but in the image of T.

This gives you by (4) that $T(V(q)) = (\sqrt{(a \cos{b})^2+(a \sin{b})^2}\cos{b},\sqrt{(a \cos{b})^2+(a \sin{b})^2}\sin{b},b)$ Now $sin^2 + cos ^2 = 1$ gives you by the distributivity ($(a \cos{b})^2+(a \sin{b})^2 = a^2*((\cos{b})^2+(\sin{b})^2$) $T(V(q)) = (\sqrt{a^2}\cos{b},\sqrt{a^2}\sin{b},b) = (a\cos{b},a\sin{b},b)$

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I want to _show_ that $T(V(q))=q$ (I know its true, but I want to see why).

Comment: @Hydrogen The equations $x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos z$ and $y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin z$ only show you that after normalization, ($x'=x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $y'=y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so that $x'^2+y'^2=1$, with the same direction), you *must* have $\cos z=x'$ and $\sin z=y'$. But that comes directly from the fact $q$ is in the *image* of $T$. *q* is **not** arbitrary. If $q$ is in the image of $T$, it means there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $x=a\cos z$ and $y=a\sin z$ and $z=b$. See?

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you to both @Jean-ClaudeArbaut and linkja